# Conditioning for differences pandas dataframe columns based on third column

Tags: pandas

In the following pandas dataframe, how do I obtain a third column 'spread' based on 'acqDis_nondrv',

```
acqDis_nondrv  Close nondrvPrice
           D      8      32.015
           A      16     5.729
           D      20     20.00
           A      16     5.729
           A      16     5.729
```

Expected Outcome

```
    acqDis_nondrv     Close  nondrvPrice  spread
               D      8      32.015.      24.015     
               A      16     5.729        10.271
               D      20     20.00        0
               A      16     5.729        10.271
               A      16     5.729.       10.271
```

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is get the differences between '`Close`' and '
`nondrvPrice`' based on `acqDis_nondrv` column.

I tried

```
df['spread']=df['Close']-df['nondrvPrice']
```

how do I add the conditions for my requirements?

- if acqDis_nondrv == 'A' then df['Close']-df['nondrvPrice'],
- if acqDis_nondrv == 'D' df['nondrvPrice']-df['Close']

Comment: Do you mean that you want the absolute difference between the columns?

Comment: What kind of conditions? Can you give an example?

Comment: condition is - if acqDis_nondrv == 'A' then df['Close']-df['nondrvPrice'], if acqDis_nondrv == 'D'  df['nondrvPrice']-df['Close']

Comment: I believe It's better if you update your question instead of adding your condition in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), like:

```
import numpy as np
df['spread'] = np.where(df['acqDis_nondrv'] == 'A', df['Close'] - df['nondrvPrice'],
                        df['nondrvPrice'] - df['Close'])
```

---

```
df

  acqDis_nondrv  Close  nondrvPrice  spread
0             D      8       32.015  24.015
1             A     16        5.729  10.271
2             D     20       20.000   0.000
3             A     16        5.729  10.271
4             A     16        5.729  10.271
```

Note that this answer assumes that your column acqDis_nondrv, can only take values 'A' and 'D', if that's not the case, please show that in your question.

Comment: This is recommended solution here in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply()` method:

```
df['spread']=df.apply(lambda x: x['Close']-x['nondrvPrice'] if x['acqDis_nondrv'] == 'A' else(x['nondrvPrice']-x['Close'] if x['acqDis_nondrv'] == 'D' else x ),axis=1)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
     acqDis_nondrv  Close   nondrvPrice     spread
0           D       8       32.015          24.015
1           A       16      5.729           10.271
2           D       20      20.000          0.000
3           A       16      5.729           10.271
4           A       16      5.729           10.271
```

**Note:**  If you are familiar with `numpy` the use `where()` method (the answer given by @sophocles) as it is more efficient(speed wise)

Comment: no, thats not correct solution - here is what I want if acqDis_nondrv == 'A' then df['Close']-df['nondrvPrice'], if acqDis_nondrv == 'D' df['nondrvPrice']-df['Close']

Comment: Where you mentioned this condition in your question?

Comment: sorry posted too early.

Comment: Updated my answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I still really surprise like people like `apply`, it is sad...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df['spread']=df['Close']-df['nondrvPrice']
df.loc[df['acqDis_nondrv'].eq('D'), 'spread'] = df['nondrvPrice'] - df['Close']
```